# Script is not pausing until I type soff

Tags: bash, scripts

The script is automatically calling the signoff script instead of pausing until I type "soff"?

Also a user should not be able to start this script "signon" again while it is running. Below is what I have so far, please help and thank you!

```
#!/bin/bash
#getname file used as my base for signon
#gets a few words of wisdom from user and prints to log.dat file

echo -n "What are your words of wisdom Grasshopper?: "
read name

    echo >> log.dat
    echo "
          -----------------------------------------------
          Signon:"     $(date) >> log.dat
    echo "          Now hear this: $name" >> log.dat

touch .running

cat <<EOF > soff
rm .running
rm soff
EOF
chmod +x soff

echo "You must type 'soff' to end this script."
while [ -f .running ]
do
   echo "I'm still running, type 'soff' to stop me :)..."
   sleep 10

done &

signoff
```

Comment: Try typing `./soff`

Comment: In another terminal.

Comment: @muru: No, the loop runs in backgrund and leaves the prompt free. I don't know if this is well or is a mistake.

Comment: Actually it works fine because I moved rm .running to the signoff script to stop it and finish writing to the log.dat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually pausing to read user input anywhere.

```
echo "You must type 'soff' to end this script."
while [ -f .running ]
do
   if read -t 10 -p "I'm still running, type 'soff' to stop me :)... " ans
   then
      if [[ $ans == "soff" ]]; then
         break
      fi
   fi
done

signoff   # shouldn't this be "soff" ?
```

`read -t` returns a failure condition if the timeout value expires, so the `if` block will not enter and you get to the next `while` loop iteration.

Also, you don't need to dynamically create a script file: use a shell function

```
signoff () {
    rm .running
    # do other stuff
}

echo "You must type 'soff' to end this script."
while ...
done

signoff   # this calls the function
```

To block multiple invocations, check the existence of the .running file as the first thing your script does.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f .running ]]; then
    echo "I'm already running (on pid $(<.running))"
    exit
fi

# put the current pid in the running file
echo $$ > .running
```

Note, there is a race condition there. I think that directory creation is atomic, so you can do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

if mkdir .running
then 
    # nobody else is running this script
    # store the pid
    echo $$ > .running/pid
else
    echo "I'm already running (on pid $(<.running/pid))
    exit
fi
signoff() {
    rm .running/pid
    rmdir .running
}
# ...
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
#!/bin/bash

if mkdir .running
then 
    # nobody else is running this script
    # store the pid
    echo $$ > .running/pid
else
    echo "I'm already running (on pid $(<.running/pid))
    exit
fi

signoff() {
    rm .running/pid
    rmdir .running
}

read -p "What are your words of wisdom Grasshopper?: " words

cat <<WISDOM >>log.dat

        -----------------------------------------------
        Signon:     $(date)
          Now hear this: $words

WISDOM

while [[ -d .running ]]
do
   if read -t 10 -p "I'm still running, type 'soff' to stop me :)... " ans
   then
      [[ $ans == "soff" ]] && break
   fi
done

signoff
```

Comment: But this doesn't run in background, and the original does. Except the run in background behavior was a mistake.